# Select2 result position is incorrect

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Normal dropdown result opens at proper position. But maximum selection message is not positioned properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by adjusting select2 results on "results:message" event as given below.

```
var $select2Container = $('#DepartmentDDL').data('select2');                        
$select2Container.on('results:message', function (params) {
                            this.dropdown._resizeDropdown();
                            this.dropdown._positionDropdown();
                         }
                    );
```

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer, worked perfectly for me